# Android Toolbar item DragListener

Tags: android

I have an Item (a cart) in my Toolbar, and I want to be able to add a DragListener to it.

What I'm trying to do, is to drag & drop my products (thanks to DragShadowBuilder) directly in my Cart, but I just can't find a way to add this listener to It. I've tried my drag & drop on a simple Floatbutton and It works as it should.

Apparently MenuItem isn't considered as a View, so I don't know how to add the listener to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I can suggest you doing two things:

### First one

Replace your `MenuItem` with item in `Toolbar`. You can do it like this:

```
<Toolbar>
  <TextView>   <!-- Title -->
  <CartView>
</Toolbar>
```

This way you can use your drag & drop like with any view

### Second one

Stay with `MenuItem`, but calculate it's position (like an top-end square in Toolbar). Then listen for dragging coordinates and compare them with position of your cart `MenuItem`. And if user releases dragged item in specified coordinates then do stuff.